# Cordova 6.1.1 iOS build fail with error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to Cordova using Mac OS and I am just running the Mac OS in virtual machine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

When I build a project for iOS platform the build fail due to this error.

[image]

The plugin only installed is whitelist which require in new version of cordova.

Additional information may need:
- I am using Yosemite hackintosh.
- Cordova v.6.1.1.
- xcode 6.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your plugin of cordova-plugin-camera?

I sugest you

- update Xcode from 6.4 to 7.0;
- remove your dir, and create a Cordova project again.

then you can try "cordova build ios" again.

Comment: Can I use xcode 7.0 in yosemite mac os? Also, I am not using cordova-plugin-camera.

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed only cordova whitelist plugin, this could not be a plugin issue. You can create a new project and port your code and try building iOS platform again. This solves the issue in most cases. Also ensure that you dont have any illegal or special characters in config.xml. Many a times, copy paste results in special characters addition in config.xml which causes this issue.

Comment: The project is just created. After that I try to build the project if everything works fine. I will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it did not work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user3472449 could you post the complete trace?

Comment: Here is the complete trace link. https://justpaste.it/tvfm
Hope this will help solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @user3472449 I could notice the following error - "error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11" I hope you upgraded to latest xcode version 7x. Try changing the following setting by navigating to Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO Also have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576693/ios-xcode-compile-error-unable-to-execute-command-segmentation-fault-11