# Can run successfully but can't archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to archive one of my projects but I keep getting an error even though I can run the simulator perfectly fine. This is the error that I keep receiving

[image]

This is interesting because I can run my app with no problem but when it comes to archiving, I seem to run into a seg fault. Any help would be appreciated :-) Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576693/ios-xcode-compile-error-unable-to-execute-command-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: This Linker error may come if you have same name class files in different folder in same project.. Check for any duplicate file names.... Or it may be because of some library files, Just remove its reference & then add it again to project...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem by updating Xcode from 7.2 -> 7.3.1