# Unity 3D iOS Build Bitcode Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build, admob

I want to enable bitcode in my iOS project everything works fine but whenever I enable bitcode and try to archive the project I get CLang error. I am using Google Admob framework 7.15.0 which supports bitcode, unity 5.4.1f1 and xCode 7.2. I am trying to solve this problem for days with no luck any help appreciated.

thanks

Below is the error I am getting

> Ld
>   /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Mushroom.app/Mushroom
>   normal armv7
>       cd /Users/zeeshanullah/Desktop/Unity/Publish
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/zeeshanullah/Desktop/Unity/Publish -L/Users/zeeshanullah/Desktop/Unity/Publish/Libraries -F/Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/zeeshanullah/Desktop/Unity/Publish -filelist /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Mushroom.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Mushroom-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt
>   -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -ObjC -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion
>   -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -weak_framework iAd -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Mushroom_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/zeeshanullah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fefeolxmzaribigaxtqjdkorlsiv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Mushroom.app/Mushroom
>
> clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 clang:
>   error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: i am beginner too. but may be it will be help you Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576693/ios-xcode-compile-error-unable-to-execute-command-segmentation-fault-11)

Comment: I've added admob framework that supports bitcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated xcode from 7.2 to the latest version 8.2 and it solved bitcode issue.